# How do you initialize a field in the State of a StatefulWidget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have something like this where a widget's color depends on a bool, and the bool flips when you tap on the widget. But I also want to initialize the bool, which will be different for different instances of the widget. I tried something like this where the `StatefulWidget` class contains the initial value `initBool`, which is used in `initState` to set `myBool`.

It seems to work (but honestly I'm not sure because I'm getting a strange bug but I can't figure out if it's related or not), but it just feels a little clunky, so I was wondering if there's a more appropriate way to do this in Flutter. Thanks!

```
class MyBox extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool initBool;
  
  MyBox(this.initBool);
  @override
  _MyBoxState createState() => _MyBoxState();
}

class _MyBoxState extends State<MyBox> {
  bool myBool;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myBool = widget.initBool;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
          color: myBool ? Colors.green : Colors.red
      ),
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          myBool = !myBool;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with what you currently have?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore It just feels a bit sketchy to have a separate variable just for the initial value, so I wanted to check with more experienced Flutter users to see if there's a better way based on best practices when using StatefulWidget.

Comment: What you currently have is perfectly fine.

Comment: Though this is probably the idiomatic way to do this, I see two issues:
1) the initial value is kept around longer than it needs to be. There's no reason to have to declare a field for it, as once the state is initialized with it, there's no more need for it
2) the field in the state class is not initialized at declaration, which for non-nullable fields and current versions of dart is an error, so it seems like you'd have to set it to a dummy value

Comment: I guess the other option is to declare the field with `late`, but I don't love that either. It seems like passing values to the state's constructor solves all of these issues, so I'm not sure why it's discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect case for WidgetsBinding

just do this after `super.initState();`:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  setState(() {
    myBool = widget.initBool;
  });
});
```

this is where you're allowed to set States directly after init.